# Reading KeePass files in Android app

Tags: android, keepass

I am currently trying to read KeePass (.kdbx V2) files within my own Android App but I am struggling. I tried to use openkeepass as a .jar but it did not work out.

Can anybody tell me a more reliable way to read keepass files in within my app - ideally an easy to use library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea well this question was kind of stupid, I should have googled for "open keepass in Java" -> there seem to be some libs out there doing the job. I chose KeePassJava2 for my app.